# Norm- finite fields.

Tags: finite-fields

Let $F$ be a finite extension of $K=\mathbb{F}_q$. Prove that for $\alpha \in F$ we have $N_{F/K}(\alpha)=1$ if and only if $\alpha=\beta^{q-1}$ for some $\beta \in F^*$.

I already proved that if $\alpha=\beta^{q-1}$ then the norm is iqual to 1. For the other implication i have this idea
 $N_{F/K}(\alpha)=\alpha^{\frac{q^m-1}{q-1}}=1$ but i know that $\alpha=\alpha^{q^m}$ because $N_{F/K}(\alpha)=  N_{F/K}(\alpha^q)$ then $\alpha^{q^m-1}=1$ so $\alpha^{\frac{q^m-1}{q-1}}=\alpha^{q^m-1}=1$.

Comment: Hint: A simple proof can be cooked up using the fact that the multiplicative group $F^*$ is cyclic of order $q^m-1$. Can you use that idea?

Comment: I used that idea, then $\alpha=a^n$ , ${1}\leq\{n}\leq {q^m-1}$ and $a$ is the generator of $F*$ but i dont't know how to proceed.

Comment: Ok. What can you say about $n$ given that $N_{F/K}(\alpha)=1$?

Comment: $n=(q-1)k$, $K \in \mathbb(Z)$? Thanks